# How to change content dynamically using Joomla 1.6

Tags: php, joomla1.6

How can I change the content according to the selection. i have given you an example below,

Consider we have a Top Menu which consists of the following :
1) Home
2) About Us
3) Contact Us

I have `slider container` which consist of Text within `<h2> Tag` , text depends on Page `if About us page then About Us is written` and so on.

So my question is `based on the above selection text will be changed dynamically`. can you please explain ?

Answer (score 0):

Install a plugin like sourcerer which lets you insert custom code as a module.

Create a custom HTML module and publish it somewhere on your code.

Edit the custom HTML module and insert jQuery commands to update the elements you want.

Joomla uses MooTools by default but there are plugins to insert jQuery.

Remember that you won't be able to use the $ alias for the jQuery command so you'll have to use the long form.

Otherwise there might be another Joomla slider that will let you do this.

Comment: I have used ur mentioned plugin .. but I dont know whats wrong ?   {source}
<!-- You can place html anywhere within the source tags -->


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"<span>></span><br><img src="/netscientific/plugins/editors-xtd/sourcerer/images/tab.png" _mce_src="plugins/editors-xtd/sourcerer/images/tab.png" alt="    ">// You can place JavaScript like this
 var title= document.getElementsByTagName('title').innerHtml;
 var headingTag = document.getElementsByClassName('slider').getElementsByTagName('a');
 headingTag.innerHtml = title ;
 
</script>{/source}

Comment: Hi,
What displays on the page?  That doesn't look like valid Javascript, has there been an issue with something inserting characters into your script?

Comment: nothing is displaying on page .. it insert script tag in my div which contains h2 tag .. even alert is not working